# Meaning of SSMS database icon preceded by scroll with red x

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

[image: Database icon preceded by scroll icon with red x]

SSMS 2008 R2, connecting to a 2008 instance shows the above glyph in SSMS Object Explorer. None of our other instances show that icon. I've moused over it in the vain hopes that I'd get a useful tooltip but to no avail.

I assume it's related to a failure we had this past weekend. Could someone provide a more authoritative response on what that icon means and any action I should direct my DBAs to take to clear it up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is documented in BOL under ["Administering Servers by Using Policy-Based Management"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

> For failed policies, Object Explorer indicates a critical health
>   warning as a red icon next to the target and the nodes that are higher
>   in the Object Explorer tree.

I've not used policy based management myself so am not entirely clear what this means. Through the UI I couldn't see any way of denoting a policy condition as having any particular severity.

I've made this answer community wiki in case someone more familiar with the subject area wants to expand upon it.

Answer (score 0):

**First try clearing the history:**

- Run #1 to obtain the Policy ID for the PBM history
- Run #2 to delete all history
- Modify date on item #2 with date from item #1's output to delete a specific failed evaluation event or events

**If clearing the history does not remove the Red X:**

- disable all policies with failed audits
- refresh instance object
- re-enable the policies you disabled

> Note: the history **MUST** be clear of failed evaluations to remove the Red X

```
 #1
```

SELECT a.name AS N'policy_name', b.policy_id, b.start_date, b.end_date
FROM msdb.dbo.syspolicy_policies AS a
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syspolicy_policy_execution_history AS b
ON a.policy_id = b.policy_id

```
#2
```

DECLARE @todayAsOldest DATETIME;

SET @todayAsOldest = (SELECT SYSDATETIME())

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_delete_policy_execution_history @policy_id = ID
, @oldest_date = @todayAsOldest;

> Note: ID is of int datatype